# zapier - Connecting BigCommerce to dear inventory

Tags: api, bigcommerce, webhooks, zapier

I am trying to pull the `customer_id` from BigCommerce and apply to the `AdditionalAttribute1` field in [dear inventory](http://dearsystems.com/inventory-software/). I am trying to accomplish this using [Zapier](https://zapier.com/).

I set it up so that it pulls info from BigCommerce. The next step would be to use a webhook and a PUT to insert it into dear inventory. How can Bigcommerce and dear inventory map the user? Is there a better alternative? Any info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you getting the customer_ID value from? The order object or the customer object?

Comment: i am getting it from the customer object, but its actually the customer_group_id:

Comment: You only get Additional Attributes if the customer record is explicitly assigned an additional attribute set. I know this is obvious to.an experienced Dear user but you are not clear about what the problem is.